# Cristóvão Colombo's name in America

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, names

How do American people usually pronounce Cristóvão Colombo's name?

For example, do Americans say "Cristopher"? Is that a correct version of this?

Or do they pronounce it like in my country (Brazil, by the way)? Do the names of people ever change?

Comment: ***Christopher Columbus*** https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christopher_Columbus - His original name was Cristoforo Colombo.

Comment: What do you mean with "the names of people never change"? You really believe that "João Baptista" was called João by his mates in Judea? Even the name of the 3rd century saint _Tarcisius_ seems to have been changed ;)

Comment: Yes, in my Country...we never change people's name...Like...if your name are "Tobey" my people never will call you "Tobias" understand me? In My Country, that is the rules  with names...

Comment: Like in here, u call me Tarcisius like the 3rd century saint, don't make any sense...cause my Name is Tarcísio...and that's it, we don't change names in Brasil, it's like disrespect, you know what i mean?

Comment: @FagnerTarcísio Well that’s clearly not true, because _Cristóvão Colombo_ was **not** his birth name; it’s his name translated/transformed into Portuguese.

Comment: For example, if you are from England...i have to pronounce you name like ur friends in England...cause that is Your name, you know what  i'm saying?

Comment: Holy mother... you totaly right, man!! I see that now...Cristoforo, right? My apollogies for my ignorance...:P

Comment: Do you mean that you never use nicknames in your country? My name is Katherine, but I like people to call me Kate. However, when I once spent some months among French-speaking people, they found 'Kate' difficult to say so they called me Katherine, pronounced in the French way.

Answer (score 2):

It was much more common in centuries past to use different names in different languages than it is now. It would have been quite normal for this person to use language-specific names. His name in English is always *Christopher Columbus*.

If we want to consider what might count  as the "original" or definitive version we have to look at the history. According to [English Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christopher_Columbus), he was Italian but he married a Portuguese person and had a Spanish mistress. He worked for both Spain and Portugal. You might think that the Italian would be the original, but Wikipedia tells us that his first language was not Standard Italian (if there was such a thing at the time) but a dialect of Ligurian.

If we look on [Ligurian Wikipedia](https://lij.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cristoffa_Combo) we find

> Cristoffa Combo pron. /kriˈstɔffa ˈkuŋbu/ (o Cömbo o Cunbu), primma d'o XIX sec. Christoffa Corombo pron. /kriˈʃtɔffa kuˈɹuŋbu/

before it goes on to tell us it was Italianized as

> Cristoforo Colombo pron. /kri'stɔffuru ku'luŋbu/

So I would go for one of these Ligurian forms.

Wikipedia's complete list is:

```
              English   Christopher Columbus    Cristoforo Colombo

                Columbus

                Cristóbal Colón

                Cristobal Colon

                Christofer Columbus

          French    Christophe Colomb   Christofer Columbus

          German    Christoph Kolumbus  Cristoforo Colombo

                Cristóbal Colón

                Cristóvão Colombo

                Christopher Columbus

                Christofer Columbus

          Scots Christopher Columbus

          Afrikaans Christophorus Columbus

          Amharic   ክሪስቶፎር ኮሎምበስ

          Aragonese Cristofo Colombo

          Old English   Christopher Columbus

          Arabic    كريستوفر كولومبوس

          Egyptian Arabic   كريستوفر كولومبوس

          Assamese  ক্ৰিষ্টোফাৰ কলম্বাছ

          Asturian  Cristóbal Colón Colón

          Aymara    Cristoforo Colombo

          Azerbaijani   Xristofor Kolumb

          South Azerbaijani کریستوفور‌کولومب

          Bashkir   Христофор Колумб

          Bavarian  Christoph Kolumbus

          Belarusian    Хрыстафор Калумб

          Belarusian (Taraškievica orthography) Хрыстафор Калюмб

          Bulgarian Христофор Колумб

          Bhojpuri  क्रिस्टोफर कोलंबस

          Bangla    ক্রিস্টোফার কলম্বাস

          Tibetan   ཁ་རི་སི་ཐོའོ་ཧྥུ་ཀོ་ལུན་སྤུ་སི།

          Breton    Kristol Goulm

          Bosnian   Kristofor Kolumbo

          Russia Buriat Христофор Колумб

          Catalan   Cristòfor Colom Cristòfol Colom

          Min Dong Chinese  Christopher Columbus

          Chechen   Колумб, Христофор

          Cebuano   Cristobal Colon

          Central Kurdish   کریستۆفەر کۆڵۆمبس

          Czech Kryštof Kolumbus

          Chuvash   Христофор Колумб

          Welsh Christopher Columbus

          Danish    Christoffer Columbus    Christofer Columbus

          Doteli    क्रिस्टोफर कोलम्बस

          Ewe   Christofer Columbus

          Greek Χριστόφορος Κολόμβος

          Canadian English  Christopher Columbus

          British English   Christopher Columbus

          Esperanto Kristoforo Kolumbo

          Spanish   Cristóbal Colón Christophorus Columbus

                Cristobal Colon

                Colón

                Colon

                Christofer Columbus

          Estonian  Christoph Kolumbus

          Basque    Kristobal Kolon

          Extremaduran  Cristóbal Colón

          Persian   کریستف کلمب

          Finnish   Kristoffer Kolumbus Cristoforo Colombo

                Cristóbal Colón

                Christofer Columbus

          Faroese   Kristoffur Kolumbus

          Friulian  Cristoforo Colombo

          Western Frisian   Kristoffel Kolumbus

          Irish Criostóir Colambas

          Gan Chinese   哥倫布 

          Scottish Gaelic   Cristoforo Colombo

          Galician  Cristovo Colón  Cristoforo Colombo

                Cristóbal Colón

                Columbus

          Guarani   Kiritóval Kolõ

          Goan Konkani  Christopher Columbus

          Swiss German  Christoph Kolumbus

          Hakka Chinese Cristoforo Colombo

          Hebrew    כריסטופר קולומבוס   קאלומבוס, קריסטאף

          Hindi क्रिस्टोफ़र कोलम्बस कोलंबस

          Fiji Hindi    Christopher Columbus

          Croatian  Kristofor Kolumbo

          Haitian Creole    Kristòf Kolon

          Hungarian Kolumbusz Kristóf

          Armenian  Քրիստափոր Կոլումբոս

          Interlingua   Christophoro Columbo

          Indonesian    Kristoforus Kolumbus

          Iloko Christopher Columbus

          Ido   Cristoforo Colombo

          Icelandic Kristófer Kólumbus

          Italian   Cristoforo Colombo  Christofer Columbus

          Japanese  クリストファー・コロンブス   コロンブス

                クリストーフォロ・コロンボ

                クリストーバル・コロン

          Jamaican Creole English   Krixtifa Kolombos

          Lojban    kristoforos.kolombos.

          Javanese  Christopher Columbus

          Georgian  ქრისტეფორე კოლუმბი

          Kara-Kalpak   Cristoforo Colombo

          Kabiye    Christophe Colomb

          Kazakh    Христофор Колумб

          Khmer ការរុករករបស់លោកគ្រីស្តុបកូឡុំ

          Kannada   ಕ್ರಿಸ್ಟೊಫರ್ ಕೊಲಂಬಸ್

          Colognian Christoph Kolumbus

          Kurdish   Krîstofor Kolumbus

          Kyrgyz    Колумб Христофор    Христофор Колумб

          Latin Christophorus Columbus

          Ladino    Kristof Kolomb

          Luxembourgish Christoph Kolumbus

          Lezghian  Христофор Колумб

          Lingua Franca Nova    Cristoforo Colombo

          Limburgish    Christoffel Columbus

          Ligurian  Cristoffa Combo

          Lombard   Cristòforo Colómbo

          Lithuanian    Kristupas Kolumbas

          Latvian   Kristofors Kolumbs

          Literary Chinese  哥倫布 

          Maithili  क्रिस्टोफर कोलम्बस

          Basa Banyumasan   Kristoforus Kolumbus

          Malagasy  Christophe Colomb

          Minangkabau   Christopher Columbus

          Macedonian    Кристофер Колумбо

          Malayalam ക്രിസ്റ്റഫർ കൊളംബസ്

          Mongolian Христофер Колумб

          Marathi   क्रिस्तोफर कोलंबस

          Western Mari  Колумб, Христофор

          Malay Christopher Columbus

          Maltese   Kristofru Kolombu

          Mirandese Cristobo Colombo

          Burmese   ကိုလံဘတ် ခရစ္စတိုဖာ

          Mazanderani   کریستفر کلمب

          Nāhuatl   Cristoforo Colombo

          Min Nan Chinese   Christophorus Columbus

          Norwegian Bokmål  Christofer Columbus

          Low German    Christoph Kolumbus

          Low Saxon Christoffel Columbus

          Nepali    क्रिस्टोफर कोलम्बस

          Newari    क्रिस्टोफर कोलम्बस

          Dutch Christoffel Columbus    Christofer Columbus

          Norwegian Nynorsk Kristoffer Columbus Christofer Columbus

          Nyanja    Christopher Columbus

          Occitan   Cristòl Colomb

          Livvi-Karelian    Kristoffer Kolumbus

          Odia  କଲମ୍ବସ  

          Ossetic   Колумб, Христофор

          Punjabi   ਕਰਿਸਟੋਫਰ ਕੋਲੰਬਸ

          Pangasinan    Christopher Columbus

          Pampanga  Christopher Columbus

          Papiamento    Cristóbal Colón

          Picard    Christophe Colomb

          Polish    Krzysztof Kolumb    Christofer Columbus

          Piedmontese   Cristòfo Colomb

          Western Punjabi   کولمبس  

          Portuguese    Cristóvão Colombo   Colombo

                Christofer Columbus

          Brazilian Portuguese  Cristóvão Colombo

          Quechua   Cristobal Colon

          Romansh   Christof Columbus

          Romanian  Cristofor Columb

          Tarantino Cristoforo Colombo

          Russian   Христофор Колумб    Колумб, Христофор

                Колумб

                Кристобаль Колон

                Колон, Кристобаль

                Коломбо, Христофоро

                Христофоро Коломбо

          Rusyn Крістофор Колумб

          Sakha Колумб, Христофор

          Santali   ᱠᱚᱞᱚᱢᱵᱚᱥ, ᱠᱨᱤᱥᱴᱚᱯᱷᱟᱨ

          Sardinian Cristoforo Colombo

          Sicilian  Cristòfuru Culommu

          Sindhi    ڪرسٽوفر ڪولمبس

          Samogitian    Kristops Kuolumbos

          Serbo-Croatian    Kristofor Kolumbo

          Sinhala   ක්‍රිස්ටෝෆර් කොලම්බස්

          Slovak    Krištof Kolumbus

          Slovenian Krištof Kolumb

          Somali    Kristoffer Kolombus

          Albanian  Cristoforo Colombo

          Serbian   Кристифор Колумбо

          Saterland Frisian Christoph Kolumbus

          Sundanese Christopher Columbus

          Swedish   Christofer Columbus

          Swahili   Kristoforo Kolumbus

          Silesian  Krzisztof Kolůmb

          Tamil கொலம்பசு

          Telugu    క్రిస్టోఫర్ కొలంబస్

          Tajik Христофор Колумб

          Thai  คริสโตเฟอร์ โคลัมบัส

          Turkmen   Hristofor Kolumb

          Tagalog   Christopher Columbus

          Turkish   Kristof Kolomb

          Tatar Христофор Колумб

          Uyghur    كولۇمبو 

          Ukrainian Христофор Колумб    Колумб

          Urdu  کولمبس  

          Uzbek Christopher Columbus

          Venetian  Cristoforo Colombo

          Veps  Kolumb Hristofor

          Vietnamese    Cristoforo Colombo

          Volapük   Cristoforo Colombo

          Võro  Kolumbusõ Christoph

          Waray Cristóbal Colón

          Wu Chinese    哥伦布 

          Kalmyk    Колумб, Христофор

          Mingrelian    ქრისტეფორე კოლუმბი

          Yiddish   קריסטאפער קאלאמבוס

          Yoruba    Christopher Columbus

          Cantonese 哥倫布 

          Zhuang    Christopher Columbus

          Zeelandic Christoffel Columbus

          Chinese   克里斯托弗·哥伦布   克里斯托弗·哥倫布

                哥倫布

                哥伦布
```

Comment: Only about 3 percent of Italians could speak Italian—meaning the standardized language based on Tuscan—at the proclamation of the Kingdom in 1861, per [Ethnologue](https://www.ethnologue.com/language/ita).

Answer (score 1):

Most names change across languages, including that of who in English is called [Christopher Columbus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christopher_Columbus).

Visiting Wikipedia and simply changing the Language will show you how diverse these changes can be, e.g. [Cristoffa Combo](https://lij.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cristoffa_Combo), [Kryštof Kolumbus](https://cs.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kry%C5%A1tof_Kolumbus) or even [Cristóbal Colón](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crist%C3%B3bal_Col%C3%B3n), as he is called in Spain.

It is a very interesting topic, and often worth a little research beforehand.